# Multisig address with a specific required signature

Tags: multi-signature

Is it possible to create a multisig address such that it has 3 public keys attached, needs 2 signatures to create a transaction, *but* one of the signatures must be from a specific public key of the 3? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redeem:

```
<pubkey3> OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY OP_1 <pubkey1> <pubkey2> OP_2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

scriptSig:

```
OP_FALSE <sig1> <sig3> <redeem>
```

or

```
OP_FALSE <sig2> <sig3> <redeem>
```